# Making an Image Picker with UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboard

I would like to make an Image Picker with an UIButton pointing to the ImagePickerView but i don't know how to proceed.

We'll say that i want to connect the ViewController "A" (with the UIButton) to the ViewController "B" (UIImagePicker).

This is what i tried : I have a storyboard with multiples ViewController, and i don't know why i can't make an IBAction from the ViewController "A" to the ViewController "B".

Should i make the ImagePickerView programatically only or can i use Storyboard?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You don't "make an IBAction from A to B", you make a segue instead. Hold Ctrl then drag from UIButton to UIViewController B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't mention that i did that. How can i link the UIImagePickerController to the segue?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "link the UIImagePickerController to the segue"? UIImagePickerController can't be added in storyboard, it can be used only in code. When press the UIButton, show the image picker, is that what you want? If yes then I can create an answer because there's not so much room in a comment.

Comment: yes it is exactly what i want, i'm sorry if my question is a bit irrelevant.

Comment: Okay check the answer, hope it will help.

Comment: ask question very clearly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36704374/3472073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController` can't be added in storyboard, so you must do that programmatically. First, create an IBAction with your UIButton:

```
- (IBAction)openImagePicker:(id)sender;
```

Your class need to adopt `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

then show image picker in `openImagePicker:` method:

```
// Check if image source is available
// In this case, photo library is always available. If you use
// UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera instead, simulator doesn't have it
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; // Create an image picker
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; // Choose source type
    picker.delegate = self; // Delegate when image is picked
    picker.allowsEditing = YES; // Allow user to edit image before choose it
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil]; // Show image picker
}
```

To use the picked image, you must implement this method of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`:

```
/**
 * @param picker The image picker
 * @param info Dictionary contains picked images and metadata...
 */
- (void)imagePickerController:(nonnull UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(nonnull NSDictionary *)info {
    // Because we allow user to edit image,
    // so we choose UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage
    // You can see other keys in UIImagePickerController class header
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    // Dismiss the picker
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });

    // Use the image here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I understood the process but i was doing another view in my storyboard for the imagepicker (which is not necessary and i didn't expect that) I will rewrite my question to make it clear for the rest and maybe usefull

Comment: Yes it is not necessary to make another view controller because UIImagePickerController has its own :)

Answer (score 2):

Answering myself, this is how i did in swift and it works (to help other people)

```
var currentImage: UIImage!

@IBAction func ImagePicker(sender: UIButton)
{
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
    {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    var newImage: UIImage

    if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else {
        return
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    currentImage = newImage
}
```